# Visualization problems

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, visualization

I am visualizing 1-dimensional curves that are periodic.  Due to periodicity, extending the domain should result in the curve being retraced and therefore remaining unchanged.  This doesn't seem to be the case and in fact when the domain is extended the curves begins to look like a surfaces instead.  It would be easy to tell is in fact the case if I knew how to subtract one parametric graph from another.  Please see the example below.

```
u[x_, y_] = Sin[x + y];

(* Shorthands for partial derivatives *)
ux[x_, y_] = D[u[x, y], x];
uy[x_, y_] = D[u[x, y], y];
uxx[x_, y_] = D[u[x, y], {x, 2}];
uyy[x_, y_] = D[u[x, y], {y, 2}];
uxy[x_, y_] = D[ux[x, y], y];


(* Invariant differential operators *)

d1[x_, y_] = (uy[x, y]*D[#, x] - ux[x, y]*D[#, y])/Sqrt[
   ux[x, y]^2 + uy[x, y]^2] &;

d2[x_, y_] = (ux[x, y]*D[#, x] + uy[x, y]*D[#, y])/Sqrt[
   ux[x, y]^2 + uy[x, y]^2] &;


(* Differential invariants *)

I01[x_, y_] = Sqrt[ux[x, y]^2 + uy[x, y]^2]

I20[x_, y_] = 
 Simplify[1/
   I01[x, y]*(uxx[x, y]*uy[x, y]^2 - 2 ux[x, y]*uy[x, y]*uxy[x, y] + 
     uyy[x, y]*ux[x, y]^2)]

I11[x_, y_] = Simplify[d1[x, y][I01[x, y]]]

I02[x_, y_] = Simplify[d2[x, y][I01[x, y]]]

I21[x_, y_] = 
 Simplify[d2[x, y][I20[x, y]] + 2 (d1[x, y][I01[x, y]])^2/I01[x, y]]

(* Domain 1 *)
r = 2 Pi;
xlow = 0;
xhigh = r;
ylow = 0;
yhigh = r;

opacityconstant = 1;

p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{I01[x, y], I11[x, y], I02[x, y]}, {x, xlow, 
   xhigh}, {y, ylow, yhigh}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[opacityconstant]}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(01\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(11\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(02\)]\)"}, PlotRange -> Full]

p2 = ParametricPlot3D[{I01[x, y], I20[x, y], I02[x, y]}, {x, xlow, 
   xhigh}, {y, ylow, yhigh}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[opacityconstant]}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(01\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(20\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(02\)]\)"}, PlotRange -> Full]

p6 = ParametricPlot3D[{I01[x, y], I02[x, y], I21[x, y]}, {x, xlow, 
   xhigh}, {y, ylow, yhigh}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[opacityconstant]}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(01\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(02\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(21\)]\)"}, PlotRange -> Automatic]

(* Domain 2 *)
r = 6 Pi;
xlow = 0;
xhigh = r;
ylow = 0;
yhigh = r;

p1 = ParametricPlot3D[{I01[x, y], I11[x, y], I02[x, y]}, {x, xlow, 
   xhigh}, {y, ylow, yhigh}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[opacityconstant]}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(01\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(11\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(02\)]\)"}, PlotRange -> Full]

p2 = ParametricPlot3D[{I01[x, y], I20[x, y], I02[x, y]}, {x, xlow, 
   xhigh}, {y, ylow, yhigh}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[opacityconstant]}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(01\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(20\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(02\)]\)"}, PlotRange -> Full]

p6 = ParametricPlot3D[{I01[x, y], I02[x, y], I21[x, y]}, {x, xlow, 
   xhigh}, {y, ylow, yhigh}, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[opacityconstant]}, 
  Mesh -> None, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(01\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(02\)]\)", 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(I\), \(21\)]\)"}, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

Comment: Your title is too general. Can you write one that more specifically describes your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is plot quality, not the code.
The answer is `MaxRecursion`

```
ParametricPlot3D[{I01[x, y], I11[x, y], I02[x, y]}, {x, 0, 
  8 \[Pi]}, {y, 0, 8 \[Pi]}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]